# Error occurs when creating a new database under Neo4j 4.0

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Debian 9.9 and the version of Neo4j is 4.0. I'm having problems creating a new database using the neo4j browser. The instruction I followed is [this](https://neo4j.com/developer/manage-multiple-databases/).

I have tried the following Cypher command:

```
create database myNewDatabase
```

However, an error pops up like this:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.NotSystemDatabaseError
Unsupported administration command: create database myNewDatabase
```

Please let me know what the error message means and how I can solve it. Thx in advance:-)

Comment: The snapshot doesn't show correctly. The error message is this:Unsupported administration command: create database myNewDatabase

Comment: I don't get why this error message is not explained in the docs. It just appears on the community sites of neo4j a few times.

Comment: The community/enterprise difference is mentioned explicitly here: https://community.neo4j.com/t/embedded-neo4j-graph-for-existing-database-in-java/14970/2

Answer (score 40):

In v. 4 (release Feb. 2020) of the ***professional*** version of Neo4j, it's easy to create new databases.  [Documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/administration/databases/)

In the ***community*** edition, it takes a hack:

```
1. Edit the file  NEO4J_HOME\conf\neo4j.conf

2. Un-comment the line:  dbms.default_database=neo4j

3. Change the neo4j  to whatever database name you want for a new database.  Note: names must have between 3 and 63 characters.   For example:   dbms.default_database=mydatabase

4. Save the file

5. (If applicable) Kill the database server, and close the browser window with the Neo4j UI

6. Start the neo4j server, and open a new browser window, pointed as usual to http://localhost:7474/

7. Both the old (default) database, "neo4j" and the one you just created will show up.  However, attempting to switch between them causes an error.   If a switch is desired, repeat the above steps starting from (3)
```

Note: the above steps will create a folder named `mydatabase`  (or whatever name you used), in  NEO4J_HOME\data\databases , and it will populate its contents.

**I personally think that switching between databases is such a BASIC operation that Neo4j ought to make it easily accessible in the Community edition!**

Answer (score 7):

I think I've got the answer to my question. It turns out that my license (the community edition) is not supported for working with multiple databases. An alternative could be [this](https://community.neo4j.com/t/create-multiple-databases-in-community-version/5025).

Comment: FYI, I found that in Neo4j 4.0, dbms.active_database has been removed from neo4j.conf. That means the alternative is no longer working.

Comment: I just noticed the same while installing neo4j; in your conf file uncomment and change the default database name parameter to whatever name you want and this adds a new database

Answer (score 0):

maybe we can create multiple neo4j instance like http://localhost:7474/neo4j1 andhttp://localhost:7475/neo4j2 and so on

and then we install a nginx for flow forwarding and proivide a server like
http://localhost:7470